# Как найти длину гипотезузы?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

найти значения длины гипотенузы в прямоугольном треугольнике с целыми сторонами, если 1 из катетов (H) Н-простое число.
H=(2<=H<=10^4)

Например вводим 3, а выводит 5

Comment: То есть задача в том, чтобы подобрать такое целое значение второго катета, при котором гипотенуза тоже будет целой? И уточните формулировку, что значит "один из катетов (Н) Н-простое число"?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Найти все возможные значения длины гипотенузы в прямоугольном треугольнике с целыми сторонами, если один из катетов имеет длину h, где h - простое число. Напоминаем, что простым называется целое положительное число, имеющее ровно 2 делителя - единицу и себя.

Answer (score 5):

Надо полагать, это задача не совсем по C++, а по школьной математике

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

а известное и **простое**, нужно найти b,c

```
a^2 = c^2 - b^2
```

как учили в 6 классе

```
a*a = (c - b)*(c + b)
```

И что теперь следует из того, что a простое - догадаетесь?

Comment: `c  = (a*a+1)/2`?

Comment: Для любого *нечетного* `a` подходящим вариантом является `c - b = 1` и `c + b = a * a`, то есть `с` и `b` могут быть соседними целыми числами возле `a * a / 2`. Для любого *нечетного* `a` мы таким способом получим Пифагорову тройку. Простота `a` лишь делает этот вариант единственным "жизнеспособным" в рамках условия задачи. То есть непонятно при чем здесь все-таки *простота* катета. В задаче больше нет никаких ограничений, для соблюдения которых нам понадобилась бы именно *простота* `a`.

Comment: @AnT, так в задаче _"выведите все возможные"_ - а простота обеспечивает единственность решения. Ну и если там есть мультитест (чтобы перебор не проходил), то вполне логично.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А, вижу, в комментариях добавлено "выведите все возможные". Автору - по попе ремнем. Это должно быть в вопросе, а не в комментарии.